# For-loop involved in Diagonal Check for Connect Four

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So I am currently coding Connect 4 on Netbeans. I have the vertical and horizontal check already made but I am having trouble with the diagonal check, specifially the for loops. Currently my code for this,

```
    public static boolean checkDiagnol(String[][] board, int counter, String playerMoving, int lastPlacedTileRow, int col) {

    for (int i = lastPlacedTileRow-1; q = col-1; i >= 0, q >=0; i--,q--){
            if (board[i][q] == playerMoving) {
                counter += 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
            if (counter > 4) {
                return true;
            }
    }
    for (int i = lastPlacedTileRow + 1, q = col +1; i < board.length, q < board[0].length; i++,q++) {

            if (board[i][q] == playerMoving) {
                counter += 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
            if (counter > 4) {
                return true;
          } 
    }
    return false;

}
```

lastPlacedTileRow is the row of the last placed tile, col is the column chosen by the user, counter is a counter used to check if there are 4 tiles in a row, and playerMoving is the current players tile.

The current problem I have is that my for loops give errors. This is my first time using two variables in a single for loop so I am not sure how it is supose to be arranged.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What errors? Update your question with the message(s).

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

You have put a semicolon instead of a comma in the first for loop.

```
for (int i = lastPlacedTileRow-1; q = col-1; i >= 0, q >=0; i--,q--){
```

this should be

```
for (int i = lastPlacedTileRow-1, q = col-1; i >= 0, q >=0; i--,q--){
```

**Logic**

I think variable i should be counted down (or up) in both the loops because we have to check below the lastPlacedTileRow in both cases.